# VueJs dynamic slot key best pratice

Tags: javascript, vue.js, key, slot

In my VueJs 2 application, I'm refactoring my code that use with named slots (to follow recommendations as `:slot` attribute is deprecated) from:

```html
<CustomComponent>
  <div slot="named-slot">foo</div>
</CustomComponent>
```

to:

```html
<CustomComponent>
  <template #named-slot>
    <div>foo</div>
  </template>
</CustomComponent>
```

But I have a problem with dynamic slots.
Before, I had:

```html
<Slider :nb-slides="3">
  <Slide v-for="n in 3" :key="n" :slot"`slide-${n}`" :someDynamicProp="...">
</Slider>
```

And when refactoring code, I have some issues with `:key`.
If I put `:key` in template:

```html
<Slider :nb-slides="3">
  <template v-for="n in 3" :key="n" #[`slide-${n}`] >
    <Slide :someDynamicProp="...">
  </template>
</Slider>
```

I got the following error:

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                       

Module Error (from ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js):
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) 

  Errors compiling template:

  <template> cannot be keyed. Place the key on real elements instead.
```

And if I put `:key` in the concrete element Slide:

```html
<Slider :nb-slides="3">
  <template v-for="n in 3" #[`slide-${n}`] >
    <Slide :key="n" :someDynamicProp="...">
  </template>
</Slider>
```

I got the following error:

```
error  `<template v-for>` key should be placed on the `<template>` tag  vue/no-v-for-template-key-on-child
```

So as the second error is an EsLint error, I decided to add `<!-- eslint-disable vue/no-v-for-template-key-on-child -->` comment to be able to build, but I'm wondering what is the best pratice in this case?

Comment: The `vue/no-v-for-template-key-on-child` is a Vue 2 rule, but the `template cannot be keyed` error implies you're running Vue 3. That implies your ESLint config incorrectly includes Vue 2 rules when it should only be Vue 3 rules.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! in fact, my application is in Vue 2, so, I don't think it comes from EsLint config, but I'll check why `template cannot be keyed` Vue3 error is popping as it should not